# Sympy error in Octave: assumption 'f' in sym is not supported

Tags: python, octave, sympy

I have installed Python 3.6 and SymPy 1.1.1. In Octave I've run the command

`pkg install -forge symbolic`

After that I loaded the package and tried 
`syms x` to see if it works. It executed sucessfully and I got

```
OctSymPy v2.6.0: this is free software without warranty, see source. 
Initializing communication with SymPy using a popen2() pipe.
Some output from the Python subprocess (pid 10580) might appear next.
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
OctSymPy: Communication established.  SymPy v1.1.1.
Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

But when I use the comand `x=sym('x','f')` I get the error:

```
error: sym: the assumption "f" is not supported in your Sympy version.
```

which doesn't make any sense because I have the newest SymPy. Has anyone an idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is no valid assumption 'f' in any SymPy version; the mentioning of version is a distraction. You are confusing assumptions and ratflag. Assumptions work like this:

```
x = sym('x', 'positive')
```

Type `assumptions('possible')` to see all supported assumptions.

Ratflags 'r' and 'f' work like this:

```
> x = sym(0.1, 'r')
x = (sym) 1/10
```

versus

```
> x = sym(0.1, 'f')
x = (sym)

   3602879701896397
  ─────────────────
  36028797018963968
```

They apply to numeric input that is meant to be put in a symbolic variable. The issue is that 0.1 and most decimal fractions are not exactly represented in binary system. So when you pass 0.1, you are actually passing 3602879701896397 / 36028797018963968.

There are two ways to handle this input:

1. Take it at face value, as 3602879701896397 / 36028797018963968. This happens with ratflag 'f'.
2. Guess that you really meant 1/10, because of how close that complicated fraction is to 1/10. This happens with ratflag 'r', and is default behavior.

(Incidentally, SymPy without Octave interface takes 1st approach by default, without attempting to guess user's intention.)

[Reference on sym](https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/function/@sym/sym.html).